# How to time response time in Django

Tags: django, templates, time

I am creating a testing app in django. I want to be able to store the start time (when the page loads) and the end time (when the student hits submit) on every question. I realize that I could do something in the view function, however I am afraid that the latency between server and client would make any calculation meaningless. I would ideally like to calculate the start and end times on the client and send them back to the server using django's tag system.

Comment: What about Chrome's or Firefox's developer tools? You can see the time for each request there.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the server-client latency is really meaningful for your app, but you could shoot two calls, initiated by the client in Javascript, one when the document is ready and one when the user submits the answer. You would send the current timestamp in those calls.

You would then analyse those calls on the server's side with django views.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden form fields. Just initialize start time on page load and end time before page submit using javascript.

in a django view it will be accesable under request.POST